# How do I setup a Crew HQ in Grand Theft Auto Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

We've got a crew of friends playing Grand Theft Auto V Online. We'll probably max out at 10-20 players.

Ideally it'd be good do have a single apartment/ garage we could all base ourselves from.

That way we could share vehicles/ guns etc. and generally pool our resources.

How would we go about setting this up, and which is the best apartment/garage to use for this sort of approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There currently isn't a way for a crew to share property.  You could all give money to one person to own an apartment you could all go to assuming that person was online.  There is no practical way to share a garage as any vehicle driven into a garage becomes a personal vehicle of the owner and they can only have one personal vehicle out at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best you could do is to all buy an apartment in the same building or just buy the same property. You could lend eachother vehicles easily, and as for guns, you can drop them on the ground if you'd like to give them away.

At least that way you'd all start in the same place when you turn the game on, and you'd all have the same garage. Not perfect but still pretty cool.

Comment: Little side note: MK2 weapons can't be dropped.